# Getting "File Properties/PublishProfilesProd/**.pubxml was ignored as it matches the set of extensions to skip when selectively publishing."

Tags: c#, web-applications, deployment, visual-studio-2017, publish

I am getting a "File Properties/PublishProfilesProd/**.pubxml was ignored as it matches the set of extensions to skip when selectively publishing." message when publishing using the Publish action in Visual Studio to publish to multiple pubxml files in a folder that is not named the PublishProfiles Folder. I am publishing by right clicking the PublishProfilesProd folder and clicking the Publish PublishProfilesProd.